# Retag [proto] as [prototype]/[protocol-buffers]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are 35 questions as of today that use the tag [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto), and all but one of them (Linux kernel-specific) had to do with at least, and usually just, one of the following topics:

1. Prototype-based OOP (half involve an R package giving support for this to some extent)
2. Protocol buffers (either Google's or Hadoop's)

It is rather ambiguous in this respect.

- Cases falling into #1 should be retagged as as [prototype].
- Cases falling into #2 should be retagged as [protocol-buffers].

Then, this should be burninated.

Comment: I retagged/untagged all that fall in category 2. I'm unsure about category 1 though.

Comment: I would say that anything not R-related should  definitely be changed.

Comment: OK, I left the questions tagged R and proto alone. That is 8 questions to be decided on...

Comment: maybe rename it to r-proto ?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer That was exactly what I was thinking. I just wasn't sure.