# This [proto]type was a failure

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

<sup>This is a reiteration of a meta-post from [2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267653/retag-proto-as-prototype-protocol-buffers)</sup>

It seems that the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag emerged again and is still used in different contexts, currently being (mis)used in 455 questions. Thus I suggest to burn the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag once and for all and retag the existing questions to the most appropriate tag.

From what I've seen there are the following categories (I'm unfamiliar with these tags, this is just what I've found):

1. [Mixed language questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto+protocol-buffers) using [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) with [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers)
2. [Mixed language questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto+grpc+-protocol-buffers) using [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) with [grpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grpc)
3. [Mostly Javascript questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto+prototype) using [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) with [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype)

   - There are also some that [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto+javascript+-prototype) use [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto)

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is ambiguous; there are two competing usages. First, the one talking about [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) and then the one talking about [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype).

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, both mentioned topics are perfectly on-topic.

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

If it's the sole tag and neither [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) nor [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) are present, then it *can* add some meaningful information, iff the question is talking about Google Protocol Buffers.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

According to the tag-wiki:

> Related to Google Protocol Buffers, borrows its name from the .proto file extension containing a protocol schema.

It's talking about protocol buffers, but we already have a tag for this: [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers). Also it's used as an abbreviation for [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) which is a completely different topic.

Comment: you'd want to update the request a little :) the JS + proto usage has spread since (unless 18 is considered "some"). Anyway, yes, [tag:proto] is an ambiguous tag and should go after disambiguation.

Comment: Would there be any negative effects from making it a synonym of [protocol-buffers]?  It seems like the descriptions overlap

Comment: @Machavity there will be a bit of a problem with questions about JavaScript's `__proto__`, but we can deal with them first, it's not like there are too many of them

Comment: Generally, the [tag:proto] tag should go. I think that all questions tagged with [tag:protocol-buffers] or [tag:grpc] (or variants such as [tag:grpc-c#] and [tag:grpc-go]) that also have the [tag:proto] tag should lose the [tag:proto] tag. At least one of the questions like that should have the [tag:python] tag added. Any question tagged with the [tag:proto] tag that should be using [tag:prototype] should be updated to include the longer tag and drop the shorter. At least one question has tag [tag:cmd] and [tag:proto]; it should be updated to use [tag:protocol-buffers] instead of [tag:proto].

Comment: we have one other small issue to consider: unfortunately, due to how the tag name escaping works, those who try to add a `__proto__` tag end up with the `proto` tag, thus creating it again if we don't synonmize. On the other hand, if we do, we might get wrongly tagged posts because folks, in general, don't give a **** about what they slap on their posts.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*Converting my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409121/this-prototype-was-a-failure#comment854567_409121) into an answer so we can get agreement and closure on this and start reworking the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag.*</sup>

Generally, the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag should go.

I think that all questions tagged with [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) or [grpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grpc) (or variants such as [grpc-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grpc-c%23) and [grpc-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grpc-go)) that also have the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag should lose the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag. At least one of the questions like that should have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag added.

Any question tagged with the [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto) tag that should be using the [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) tag should be updated to include the longer tag and drop the shorter.

At least one question has tag [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) and [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto); it should be updated to use [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) instead of [proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proto).